# Aggregation on Aggregation in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection of documents having states, district and villages in India.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a5f8f7b5013ad477564"),
    "district" : "Chittor",
    "state" : "Andhra Pradesh",
    "village" : "Chittoor"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad477566"),
    "district" : "Dibrugarh",
    "state" : "Assam",
    "village" : "Dibrugarh"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad47756d"),
    "district" : "Lakhimpur",
    "state" : "Assam",
    "village" : "Kadam"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad47756e"),
    "district" : "Sonitpur",
    "state" : "Assam",
    "village" : "Helem"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad477572"),
    "district" : "Gandhinagar",
    "state" : "Gujarat",
    "village" : "Mansa"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad477573"),
    "district" : "Gandhinagar",
    "state" : "Gujarat",
    "village" : "Kalol"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db5a628f7b5013ad477574"),
    "district" : "Ahmadabad",
    "state" : "Gujarat",
    "village" : "Barwala"
}
```

I want to group it by state, district and village in such a way that I the result in below format

```
[
  {
    "state": "Gujarat",
    "districts": [
      {
        "district": "Gandhinagar",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Mansa"
          },
          {
            "village": "Kalol"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "district": "Ahmadabad",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Barwala"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "Assam",
    "districts": [
      {
        "district": "Sonitpur",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Helem"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "district": "Lakhimpur",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Kadam"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "district": "Dibrugarh",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Dibrugarh"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
    "districts": [
      {
        "district": "Chittor",
        "villages": [
          {
            "village": "Chittor"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried but did not find a way to get such aggregation.

```
1) db.historical_prices.aggregate({$group: {_id: {"state": "$state"}}}, {$group: {_id: {"commodity": "$commodity"}}})

2) db.places.aggregate()
      .match(qb.where("enabled").eq(false))
      .group({ _id: {"state": "$state", "district": "$district"}, "districts": {$push: {district: "$district"}}, })
```

I worked out such kind of aggregation in `elasticsearch`.

```
GET /places/_search
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_district": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "district.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_village": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "village.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get this in `MongoDB`? Because I don't want to use `elasticsearch` just for doing this.

Comment: Updated it with attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. The below query `$group` on `state` and `district` to accumulate `villages` followed by `$group` on `state` to accumulate `district` and previously collected `villages`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {state:"$state", district:"$district"},
        "villages":{$addToSet:{village:"$village"}}
    }
},{
    $group: {
        _id: {state:"$_id.state"},
        "districts":{$push:{villages:"$villages", district:"$_id.district"}}
    }
}])
```